# Google drive api name contains search query. How to down load files by extension type?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am attempting to download either .pdfs or .xml files from two separate google drive folders. I can get the Python code to work in other folders that only contain the .pdfs and .xml files. The problem is that the production folders contain other files and folders that I do not want to download. Is there a way to only download files by extension type? If so, please help with Python in mind.

The reason I ask is because I have been unsuccessful querying by "'name contains 'blah'"

```
import google_drive.constants as c
import os
import io
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

service = Create_Service(c.CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, c.API_NAME, c.API_VERSION, c.SCOPES)


def compare_file_dates(df):
    # Convert to datetime
    df['createdTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['createdTime'])
    # Find the row with the latest createdTime timestamp
    row = df[df.createdTime == df.createdTime.max()]
    latest = row['id'][0]
    print(latest)

    return latest


def get_latest_file(folder_id):
    query = f"parents = '{folder_id}'"
    fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name contains 'Quote' or name contains 'FGT', createdTime, mimeType)"
    response = service.files().list(q=query, fields=fields).execute()
    files = response.get('files')
    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    while next_page_token:
        response = service.files().list(q=query, fields=fields).execute()
        files.extende(response.get('files'))
        next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    df = pd.DataFrame(files)
    latest_file = compare_file_dates(df)

    return latest_file


def download_files():
    pdf_id = get_latest_file(c.PDF_FOLDER_ID)
    xml_id = get_latest_file(c.XML_FOLDER_ID)
    file_ids = [pdf_id, xml_id]
    file_names = ['expense.pdf', 'sell.xml']

    for file_id, file_name in zip(file_ids, file_names):
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fd=fh, request=request)

        done = False

        while not done:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print('Download progress {0}'.format(status.progress() * 100))

        fh.seek(0)

        with open(os.path.join('google_drive/downloads', file_name), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(fh.read())
            f.close()


download_files()
```

Here is the error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=parents+%3D+%271hMqacHtVlLOM1sD9cLsxm5jh4a7RHSGl%27&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name+contains+%27Quote%27+or+name+contains+%27FGT%27%2C+createdTime%2C+mimeType%29&alt=json returned "Invalid field selection nextPageToken, files(id, name contains 'Quote' or name contains 'FGT', createdTime, mimeType)". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalidParameter', 'message': "Invalid field selection nextPageToken, files(id, name contains 'Quote' or name contains 'FGT', createdTime, mimeType)", 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fields'}]">

I believe the issue is figuring out the correct format or encoding for the "name contains 'Quote' or name contains 'FGT'".

The PDF file has names that start with the 'Quote' but end with random characters. Example would be 'Quote123456.pdf'. The XML file has a similar naming structure so 'FGT1236098.xml'. Do I need a wild card character on the "name contains 'Quote'"?

Is this the correct encoding for the above "name contains 'Quote' or name contains 'FGT'" search query? name+contains+%27Quote%27+or+name+contains+%27FGT%27%

new error

> 2022-06-19 06:21:59.658560 - Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'createdTime'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\main.py", line 12, in run
> download_files()  # Get the latest xml and pdf from Google Drive
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\google_drive\google_drive_sub_task.py", line 42, in download_files
> xml_id = get_latest_file(c.XML_FOLDER_ID)
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\google_drive\google_drive_sub_task.py", line 35, in get_latest_file
> latest_file = compare_file_dates(df)
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\google_drive\google_drive_sub_task.py", line 13, in compare_file_dates
> df['createdTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['createdTime'])
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
> File "C:\Automations\GetMargins\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err
> KeyError: 'createdTime'

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Hi DalmTo - will this work?

Answer (score 0):

When you are listing your files. You should search on the types of files you want.

Currently you have

```
query =  f"parents = '{folder_id}'"
```

try adding

```
query =  f"parents = '{folder_id}' and (mimeType='application/pdf' or mimeType='application/xml')"
```

Check [search refrence](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms)

Comment: Hi DalmTo - I made the suggested update and it appear to recognize the pdf file id from drive. However, the new error listed above occurred. It appears to be an issue with the file date comparison function. Any suggestions?

Comment: I cant help with a **KeyError: 'createdTime'** error its unrelated to your original question.  You may want to try debugging it.